# Download latest file using wget

Tags: linux, bash, web, wget

I'm trying to figure out how to download the most recent file from a server using wget on my Linux system. The files are ssl certs in zip archives for some services i.e. prometheus.my.domain-09.28.2020, alertmanager.my.domain-09.28.2020, my.domain-07.28.2020, etc. The date of its addition to the server is nailed to the name of the file.Currently, i have python script that helps me to cope with the task, but due to the presence of crutches, I want to switch to bash.
I achieved stdout and sed and saving to a txt file without html tags.

```
wget -qO- https://myserver@my.domain/ssl/ | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' > downloaded_file.txt
```

The result of the command can be seen in the file:

```
prom.my.domain-2020-09-18.zip                   18-Sep-2020 18:14                7217
prom.my.domain-2020-09-21.zip                   21-Sep-2020 17:20                7217
grafana.my.domain-2020-09-18.zip                18-Sep-2020 18:14                7222
grafana.my.domain-2020-09-21.zip                21-Sep-2020 17:20                7222
my.domain-2020-09-18.zip                       18-Sep-2020 18:14                7269
my.domain-2020-09-21.zip                       21-Sep-2020 17:20                7269
```

How to download the latest grafana.zip now?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to get files.  It looks like you would likely need to use grep to narrow it down to just graphana stuff, as well as just look at filenames which would require a cut command.   `cat downloaded_file.txt | grep grafana | cut -d" " -f1` and then just walk dates backwards or something.

Comment: No, @LéaGris, it doesn't. He stated that he's trying to get away from his current python solution.

Comment: @tink The question is not more focussed on one problem. Poster did not show an attempt at solving the problem. He replaces the perfectly valid python html parser by a sed script that is improper to parse html. Will have to deal with sort, date, or eventually awk, but he does not know about any of it and any bash yet. (this is exactly what makes the question too broad). And duplicating the question will not make it less broad.

Comment: I agree with all these points, but it doesn't make it a duplicate. The approach taken is very kludgy, even when wanting a shell-only variant using `lynx` or `w3m` with the `-dump` feature would be nicer than `wget & sed` ...

Comment: @tink Thank you for help. Yes, you are right, there is more to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
wget https://myserver@my.domain/ssl/$(grep -oE "^grafana[^[:space:]]+" downloaded_file.txt | sort | tail -n 1)
```